# (Swift) Navigation bar is hidden in viewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I want to present SecondVC from FirstVC and make SecondVC have a rightBarButtonItem called `Close` which calls an `@objc` function which dismisses SecondVC. 
Also, I want to change secondVC's title from firstVC:

This is how I present SecondVC from the FirstVC:

```
let secondVC = AdviceDetailsViewController()
secondVC.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
secondVC.title = "Example" //Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'myTitle'
self.present(secondVC, animated: true)
```

Code for navigationBar in secondVC:

```
public var myTitle: String = ""
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .gray
    self.title = myTitle
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = UIColor.orange
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Close", style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(closeDetails))
}

@objc func closeDetails() {
    self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

No Navigation bar is visible in secondVC, the only visible thing is gray background color.

What should I change? I am doing everything programmatically in this app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this method to show second VC

```
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: AdviceDetailsViewController())
nc.modalPresentationStyle = . fullScreen
self.present(nc, animated: true)
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Thanks, do you have an idea why couldn't I update SecondVC's title through FirstVC like : `nc.title = "example"`

Comment: first you create public variable on secondVC, then assign that variable before show secondVc in first VC `let vc = SecondViewController()
        vc.myTitle = "My Title"
        let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
        nc.modalPresentationStyle = . fullScreen
        self.present(nc, animated: true)`

Comment: I have already tried that and assigned `self.title = myTitle in viewDidLoad` in secondVC but id didnt work. `vc.` cannot find secondVc's variable myTitle.

Comment: `Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'myTitle'`

Comment: you must define that variable on second VC `public var myTitle:String?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.title = myTitle
    }`

Comment: I did but I cant get it from firstVC

Comment: can you add the firstVC and SecondVC codes that you trying

Comment: I have updated my question. Note that I needed to set value in secondVC for myTitle because it needs an initializer to be used in viewDidLoad

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your Title issue, 
*Value of type 'UINavigationController' has no member 'myTitle'* Yes its true, because we define myTitle variable on SecondVC,So we assign myTitle like this

```
let vc = SecondViewController()
vc.myTitle = "My Title"
let nc = UINavigationController(rootViewController: vc)
nc.modalPresentationStyle = . fullScreen
self.present(nc, animated: true)
```

Comment: Looks a bit hardcoded to do this way but as long as it works good...:)
Thanks mate!